# Argmax - differentiate between array having same values and array having largest zeroth component

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, argmax

I am implementing the `argmax` function form `numpy` library to get the index of the largest element in a vector. Following is my code.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([2, 0, 0, 0, 0])
idx = np.argmax(a)  # Works fine, returns 0

b = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
idx = np.argmax(b)  # Returns 0 again
```

From the above piece of code, just by looking at `idx` variable it is impossible to differentiate if the input to `argmax` was `a` or `b`.

My code has a similar setup where I do not know the input data apriori and am allowed to take the `argmax` of the data I receive. The data can contain entries that are all the same integer values or it can have one maximum value (compared to the rest) in any of the five index positions. When the maximum occurs at the zeroth position, however, the rest of my code fails as I assume that the first index position contains the maximum value.

Is there any other form of `argmax` in python that can return `None` (or anything other than `0`) to indicate there is no one maximum value in the input data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([2, 0, 0, 0, 0])
idx = np.argmax(a) if ~np.all(a == a[0]) else None
print(idx)  # 0

b = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
idx = np.argmax(b) if ~np.all(b == b[0]) else None
print(idx)  # None

# Alternative solution

a = np.array([2, 0, 0, 0, 0])
idx = np.argmax(a) - np.all(a == a[0]).astype(int)
print(idx)  # 0

b = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
idx = np.argmax(b) - np.all(b == b[0]).astype(int)
print(idx)  # -1
```